# MouseEventHandler additional parameters - "sender" and "e" cannot be defined

Tags: c#, event-handling, argument-passing

I want to pass an argument to an event handler which I am trying to achieve with this code:

```
    private void openInputImagesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        pb.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler((sender,e) => showLargeImage(sender,e,imageIndex));
    }

    private void showLargeImage(object sender, MouseEventArgs e, int imageIndex)
    {
        ...
    }
```

However, I am getting an error on "sender" and "e" variables inside the adapter:

```
A local variable named 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'sender', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else.

A local variable named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'sender', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't name the parameter of your lambda method `sender` and `e`, as the compiler tells you.

It would create a ambiguity between the parameter `sender` of the `openInputImagesToolStripMenuItem_Click` method and the parameter of the lambda method.

Just use other names, like

```
pb.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler((s, e1) => showLargeImage(s, e1,imageIndex));
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be enough to change `sender` to something else, say `se`:

```
 pb.MouseDoubleClick += 
              new MouseEventHandler((se,e) => showLargeImage(se,e,imageIndex));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have redefinition of `sender` and `e` inside your lambda and that is no allowed:

```
private void openInputImagesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    pb.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler((s,x) => showLargeImage(sender,e,imageIndex));
}
```